# two similar plugins in Dynamics CRM 2016 ONPREMISE to merge into one

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I have two similar plugins in Dynamics CRM 2016 ONPREMISE to merge into one.

They're

1. registered to the same entity,
2. both triggered by update message,
3. one plugin check value of 3 fields, the other check value of 4 fields. If all equal to a specified value, then go on. If not, return.
   4.set, map or calculate the value from old record to new record. two plugins handle two sets of fields.
4. create a new record.

What I can think is "if else-if " structure. But it looks so naive. Anybody have any advice?

The other plugin checks 3 other fields and execute similar action creating new record with some other fields set or mapped.

Thanks,

```
protected void ExecuteApplication(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {

        IPluginExecutionContext context = null;
        IOrganizationService service = null;
        ITracingService tracer = null;
        context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
        service = localContext.OrganizationService;
        tracer = localContext.TracingService;

try
        {
            // ensure we have an application and update message 
            Entity application = new Entity(applicationEntityName);

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {

                application = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (!application.LogicalName.ToLower().Equals(this.applicationEntityName))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            if (context.MessageName.ToLower() != "update")
            {
                return;
            }                

            // Fetch data from PreImage
            Entity postImageApplication = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];



            //check three fields are not null
            if (application.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statuscode") == null ||
                postImageApplication.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_service").Name == null ||
                postImageApplication.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_source").Name == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (
                application.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statuscode").Value == 881780003 &&
                postImageApplication.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_service").Name == "CIC" 
                )

            // process if the update meets the criteria 
            {

                Entity newApplication = new Entity("new_application");
                // set 
                newApplication.Attributes.Add("new_effectiveapplication", true);
                newApplication.Attributes.Add("new_confirmdate", DateTime.Now);
                newApplication.Attributes.Add("new_signdate", DateTime.Now);

                //mapped 

                if (postImageApplication.Attributes.Contains("new_client"))
                {
                    newApplication.Attributes.Add("new_client", postImageApplication["new_client"]);
                }
                if (postImageApplication.Attributes.Contains("new_servicecentre"))
                {
                    newApplication.Attributes.Add("new_servicecentre", postImageApplication["new_servicecentre"]);
                }


                service.Create(newApplication);


            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: How to suggest anything without seeing the code?

Answer (score 2):

I like to abstract unwieldy predicates into their own method.

How about something like this:

```
private bool allFieldsHaveValues()
{
    return application.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statuscode") != null 
        && postImageApplication.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_service").Name != null 
        && postImageApplication.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_source").Name != null;
}

private bool valuesAreValid()
{
    return application.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statuscode").Value == 881780003 
        && postImageApplication.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_service").Name == "CIC";
}

if (allFieldsHaveValues() && valuesAreValid())
{
    Entity newApplication = new Entity("new_application");
```

Comment: It looks great, make the condition check simple.